# PHP & MySQL , Fetch table

Tags: php, mysql

I have to make this code return the same results but only where userID is a number (ex 16);
Every device has an userid and an username in this table.
This is the code :

```
<?php 

$myQuery= 'SELECT * FROM devicesissued di LEFT JOIN usercred uc ON di.userID = uc.userID WHERE 1 ORDER BY timeStamp DESC';
$result = mysql_query($myQuery) or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $catQuery = 'SELECT * FROM deviceinventory WHERE deviceID = '. $row['deviceID'];
    $catResult = mysql_query($catQuery) or die($catQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $cat = mysql_fetch_array($catResult);
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['displayName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['deviceID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $cat['barCodeID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $cat['category'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['deviceName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $cat['operatingSystem'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $cat['serialNumber'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $cat['macAddress'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['timeStamp'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

If I add the `WHERE 'userID' = A-Number` clause it doesn't do anything.

If you have any ideas I will be glad to try them.

Thank you.

Comment: `mysql` extension = `bad idea`...

Comment: `WHERE 1 ORDER` why `1` here?

Comment: Are you really adding WHERE 'userID' with quotes? That means you are comparing the string with ID, not a column value. The query should be `SELECT * FROM devicesissued di LEFT JOIN usercred uc ON di.userID = uc.userID WHERE uc.userId = 16 ORDER BY timeStamp DESC`

Comment: Like Hackerman said, `mysql` extension is deprecated. Use either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam `WHERE 1` in query is optional. It doesn't do anything much. It produces the same effect as without it will produce. Also, like you asked why it should be there, he could remove it to avoid confusions.

Comment: @Perumal93 yes it does nothing , I thought he wrongly added `1` for instead of `limit 1`

Comment: Replace `WHERE 1` with `WHERE di.userID = A-Number` or if you have any good reason (which I can't imagine to be honest) for `WHERE 1` you have to say `WHERE 1 AND di.userID = A-Number`. And as @Hackerman already said - do yourself a favor and don't use `mysql` extension.

Comment: @Perumal93 , I'm not so good with the sintax, sorry for that. it's userID = number.
-Hackerman , I know it's deprecated, I will try to convert the entire website to mysqli.
If I try to do the same in phpMyAdmin it's working.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much, it's working with di.userID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your query a little bit

```
$myQuery= 'SELECT * FROM devicesissued di 
             LEFT JOIN usercred uc ON di.userID = uc.userID 
             WHERE di.userID=the_number_here ORDER BY timeStamp DESC';
```

As you have the userID in both joined tables (`deviceissued` and `usercred`), you have to tell MySQL on which table you want to perform the `WHERE`-clause.